# Let $V$ the set of polynomial $f$ of coefficients real of degress not major to 4...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ the set of polynomial $f$ of coefficients real of degress not major to 4 such that $f(1)=f(-1)=0$. Prove $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}$$_4$$_[$$_x$$_]$
and prove is basis of $V$

**Proof:**
Let $f_1(x)=a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+a_4x^3+a_5x^4$ and $f_2(x)=b_1+b_2x+b_3x^2+b_4x^3+b_5x^4$ in $V$, We need show $f_1(x)+f_2(x) \in V$ and $af_1(x)\in V$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Note that:
$f_1(x)+f_2(x)=a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+a_4x^3+a_5x^4+b_1+b_2x+b_3x^2+b_4x^3+b_5x^4$
Then $f_1(1)+f_2(1)=a_1+a_2(1)+a_3(1)+a_4(1)+a_5(1)+b_1+b_2(1)+b_3(1)+b_4(1)+b_5(1)=0+0=0\in V$

On the other hand,
$c(f_1(x))=a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+a_4x^3+a_5x^4=ca_1+ca_2x+ca_3x^2+ca_4x^3+ca_5x^4.$ 
Then 
$f_1(1)=c(a_1+a_2(1)+a_3(1)^2+a_4(1)^3+a_5(1)^4)=c(0)=0\in V$

Then, $V$ is subset of $\mathbb{R}$$_4$$_[$$_x$$_]$.

Now, i'm working in the basis of this space. But, this proof is correct? I have that doubt.

If someone can give me a hint for the basis, i will be very grateful.

Comment: $f(1)=0$ gives you a (homogeneous, linear) equation relating the coefficients. $f(-1)=0$ gives you another, independent of the first. Do you know how to solve two equations in five unknowns, how to find a basis for the space of all solutions?

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks. I did the proof of subspaces with your hint now i think a basis of that space

Comment: I also gave a hint as to how to find a basis – do you know how to solve a system of two homogeneous linear equations in five unknowns? do you know how to find a basis for the vector space of all solutions?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I was thinking un a basis bit i dont know how find the basis can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of all polynomials of dergee at most 4 is 5. We have two independent conditions, $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=0$, so we get a subspace of dimension 3. There are systematic ways to go about finding a basis, but here's an ad hoc way that gets you there faster:

We just need to find three linearly independent elements of the subspace. Clearly, $p_1(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$ is in the subspace, as are all of its multiples. So, $p_2(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$ and $p_3(x)=x^2(x-1)(x+1)$ are in the subspace. Also, $\{\,p_1,p_2,p_3\,\}$ is a linearly independent set, since the three polynomials are of different degrees. So, there's a basis.